# QProcess error QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess

Всем привет. Есть вот такой код:

```
QString test = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start(test);
```

Но когда в пути есть пробелы `QProcess` выдает ошибку:

> Unknown error

Как запустить файл с пробелами в пути с помощью `QFileDialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда, нужно открыть [документацию](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) и почитать. Там все написано. Ответ прост - нужно взять в кавычки.

```
process->start("\"" + test + "\"");
```

правда, если есть кавычки внутри строки, то задача будет чуть сложнее.

Comment: Благодарю, видел такое в документации, но немного не понял как юзать.